# A resistor limits current or voltage?

Tags: voltage, current, resistors

I want to know if a resistor limits current or voltage? For example, I am getting a supply of 250V & 5A, and i have used 2 bulbs rated 15W & 250V in parallel. Do i need a resistor in the circuit?

Comment: A resistor limits current.

A power supply of 250V and 5A can supply 1250VA, so the power supply should be able to handle 15W * 2 = 30W just fine.

I have no idea why you think that a resistor could possibly belong anywhere in this circuit.

Comment: Don't you think that the current will be too much for the bulbs to handle?

Comment: The supply will provide whatever current needed for the bulbs, in the limit of 5A. So, here, they'll provide 2 x 60mA (15W/250V), not more. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings/34746. And a resistor limits neither current nor voltage, it just induces a relationship between them.

Comment: @AkshitBansal You have clearly done ZERO research into your own question. A google search, or 30 seconds of reading an introductory circuits book would give you your answer.

Comment: @AkshitBansal I recommend to study some basic literature about electronics, because we can't discuss the very basics here.

Answer (score 1):

both of them, because they have power limit which means V*I< Power limit , but this is true for all of elements, now you have resistor which its voltage corresponds to its current with ohm's law V=RI, so if you rewrite the inequality you will get RI^2

Answer (score 0):

To clarify your questions:

*Do i need a resistor in the circuit?*  In this setup you describe you do not need a resistor.

*A resistor limits current or voltage?*  If you would add a resistor in series to your power supply it would reduce the current taken from the supply and limit the voltage at your bulbs.

hope it helps

Comment: So, does that mean that resistors reduce voltage in series and current in parallel?

Comment: Only when in series. A resistor parallel to your bulbs won't effect the voltage (unless you add a very low resistor in parallel which would cause a short-circuit fault on your power supply)